# MQTT in Android Studio with Java

Tags: java, android-studio, textview

I'm new in the android world. I was trying to use an mqtt protocol to send info from a client (publisher) to a topic and retrieve from another client (subscriber) the info from the topic. For the first part it's ok, I'm able to send info to the topic and read them from the subscriber.

I would like to screen the information retrieved in textViews.
Now the problem is, the textView doesn't set the new arrived text.
Check that I did:

- the program is correctly entering in the messageArrived method (printing the message received I can see them in the log)
- the textView are visible, if I write at the beginning some text I can see it

This is the messageArrived method:

```
          public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
            String str = new String(message.getPayload());
            System.out.println(str);
            String[] info = str.split(",");
            Date sunset = new Date(Integer.parseInt(info[5]) * 1000);
            Date sunrise = new Date(Integer.parseInt(info[6]) * 1000);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE,MMMM d,yyyy h:mm,a");
            textView.setText("Last update at "+info[2]);
            textView2.setText("Humidity "+info[3]);
            textView3.setText("Sunset "+sdf.format(sunset));
            textView4.setText("Sunrise: "+sdf.format(sunset));
            textView5.setText(info[4]);
            temp.setText(info[1]);
            city.setText(info[0]);
            vibrator.vibrate(500);
            myRingtone.play();
          }
```

The string str is like:

**Rome,11,Thursday-04-15 10:37:40,100.0,drizzle,1.618508059E9,1.618460677E9**

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try `runOnUiThread` method because `onMessageArived()` is a client thread.

```
public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) 
throws Exception {
String msg = new String(message.getPayload());
Log.i(TAG, "Message Arrived: " + msg);
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
   public void run() {
       textView.setText(msg);
   }
});
}
```